# How to set session timeout on backend advanced template?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm successfully implemented session time out in frontend in advance template with this code

`frontend\config\main.php`

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'homeUrl' => '/myweb',


    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
            'formatter' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
                    'thousandSeparator' => '.',
                    'decimalSeparator' => ','
                    //'currencyCode' => '$'
            ],
        //session time out code here
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserCustomer',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            //'enableSession' => true,
              'authTimeout' => 3600,
        ],
        'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'cookieparams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 3600],
            'timeout' => 3600,
            'useCookies' => true,
        ],
        //end session time out
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
         'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/myweb',
    ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,

];
```

But I wonder how I implement in backend if I have multiple user for administrator.

Here is my `backend\config\main.php`

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    //multiple user here
    'modules' => [
        'agent' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\agent\Agent',
        ],
        'company' => [
                'class' => 'backend\modules\company\Company',
                'defaultRoute' => 'home',
        ],
        'vendor' => [
                'class' => 'backend\modules\vendor\Vendor',
                'defaultRoute' => 'default',
        ],
        'services' => [
                'class' => 'backend\modules\services\Services',
                'defaultRoute' => 'site',
        ],


    ],
    'homeUrl' => '/myweb/administrator',
        'components' => [

        'formatter' => [
                        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
                        'thousandSeparator' => '.',
                        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
                        //'currencyCode' => '$'
                ],
        // this code has no effect after 60 second inactivity
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserBeo',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60
        ],
        'session' => [
           'class' > 'yii\web\Session',
           'cookieparams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 60],
           'timeout' => 60,
           'useCookies' => true,
        ],
       // end session time out
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
         'urlManager' => [
         'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,
             /*
                'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),

              */
        ],
        'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/myweb/administrator',

        'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ]

        ],
                /*
                'response' => [
                        'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                        'charset' => 'UTF-8',
                        // ...
                ]
                */

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

after implement code just like frontend in backend, the session time out code has no effect after 60 second of inactivity,

is there something wrong with my code?

anyway here is my `common\models\UserBeo` code

```
<?php

namespace common\models;


use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use common\models\TbUserAgent;
use common\models\TbUserCompany;
use common\models\TbUserVendor;

class UserBeo extends \yii\base\Model implements IdentityInterface
{
    //tipe aktor, 0 untuk customer, 1 untuk company
    private $username = '';
    private $user_id = '';
    private $email = '';
    private $password = '';
    private $jenis_user = '';
    private $AktorType = '';
    private $user_status ='';
    private $is_agent = '';


        public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password','jenis_user'], 'required'],
            [['email'], 'email'],
            [['email','password','jenis_user'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    function UserBeo($aktor_type)
    {
        $this->AktorType = $aktor_type;

    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getAuthKey() {
        return null;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        //not implemented
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        if($this->AktorType == EAktorType::Customer)
        {
            $user =  TbCustomer::find()->where("customer_id = $id")->one();
            $userbeo = new UserBeo();
            $userbeo->setEmail($user->email);
            $userbeo->setUser_id($user->customer_id);
            $userbeo->setUsername($user->username);
            $userbeo->is_agent = $user->is_agent;
            $userbeo->jenis_user = EAktorType::Customer;
            return $userbeo;
        }
        else if ($this->AktorType == EAktorType::Company)
        {
            $user =  TbUserCompany::find()->where("user_id = $id")->one();
            $userbeo = new UserBeo();
            $userbeo->setEmail($user->email);
            $userbeo->setUser_id($user->user_id);
            $userbeo->setUsername($user->username);
            $userbeo->jenis_user = EAktorType::Company;
            return $userbeo;

        }
        else if ($this->AktorType == EAktorType::Agent)
        {
            $user =   TbUserAgent::find()->where("user_id = $id")->one();
            $userbeo = new UserBeo();
            $userbeo->setEmail($user->email);
            $userbeo->setUser_id($user->user_id);
            $userbeo->setUsername($user->username);
            $userbeo->jenis_user = EAktorType::Agent;
            return $userbeo;
        }
        else if ($this->AktorType == EAktorType::Vendor)
        {
            $user = TbUserVendor::find()->where('user_id = $id')->one();
            $userbeo = new UserBeo();
            $userbeo->setEmail($user->email);
            $userbeo->setUser_id($user->user_id);
            $userbeo->setUsername($user->username);
            $userbeo->jenis_user = EAktorType::Vendor;
            return $userbeo;
        }
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        //not implemented
    }

    //dibawah ini hanya getter dan setter saja
       function getUser_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    function getJenis_user() {
        return $this->jenis_user;
    }

    function getAktorType() {
        return $this->AktorType;
    }

    function getUser_status() {
        return $this->user_status;
    }

    function setUser_id($user_id) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    function getIs_agent() {
        return $this->is_agent;
    }

    function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function setJenis_user($jenis_user) {
        $this->jenis_user = $jenis_user;
    }

    function setAktorType($AktorType) {
        $this->AktorType = $AktorType;
    }

    function setIsagent($AktorType) {
        $this->is_agent = $AktorType;
    }

    function setUser_status($user_status) {
        $this->user_status = $user_status;
    }

    function setUsername($user_name) {
        $this->username = $user_name;
    }

}
```

`UserAgent`, `UserCompany`, and `UserVendor` is user type for backend.

So `UserAgent`, and `UserVendor` can login in frontend and backend, but `UserCompany` only login for backend.

If you need other information please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is still `user` component configuration in your code for backend - why not there?

Comment: Does it work at all? You are using old way to override construct which is not valid anymore.

Comment: @Bizley it work for frontend

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here if you say the timeout works on frontend but not on backend and the configuration for both is basically the same.